# fpm is not recognised if executing script with jenkins and ssh

Tags: jenkins, ssh

I am trying to execute a script over ssh connexion with Jenkins. I am using the [SSH plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+plugin) and it is well configured. I arrive to execute the first part of the script, but when I try to execute a fpm command it says:

```
fpm: command not found
```

If I connect to the instance and run the same script that I call via Jenkins it runs and there is no error (fpm is installed).

So, I have created a test like a script test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash -x 
fpm
```

but, with Jenkins, I get the same error: `fpm: command not found`, while if I execute it I get a normal "parameter needed":

```
Missing required -s flag. What package source did you want? {:level=>:warn}
Missing required -t flag. What package output did you want? {:level=>:warn}
No parameters given. You need to pass additional command arguments so that I know what you want to build packages from. For example, for '-s dir' you would pass a list of files and directories. For '-s gem' you would pass a one or more gems to package from. As a full example, this will make an rpm of the 'json' rubygem: `fpm -s gem -t rpm json` {:level=>:warn}
Fix the above problems, and you'll be rolling packages in no time! {:level=>:fatal}
```

What am I missing? Why it cannot find fpm if it is installed?

Comment: When you did the test on the node (or the instance), did you use the same linux user? (the one you used with the SSH plugin). Maybe the PATH is different for this user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem came because the `fpm` was installed in the `/home/user2connect/bin/`, and the command was not recognised. For fixing this I had to call it wit the whole path:

```
/home/user2connect/bin/fpm ...
```

I have chosen to reinstall the `fpm` using `sudo`, so now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure fpm is in /usr/bin..